# Django ImportError: Couldn't import Django When Use Docker

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I am getting an error in console while trying to use docker. How to fix it
but when I test With  localhost it just work.

[image]

error

```
PS C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Projects\Testadmin\master> docker-compose up
Creating network "master_default" with the default driver
Creating master_web_1 ... done
Attaching to master_web_1
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
web_1  |     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
web_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
web_1  |
web_1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
web_1  |
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
web_1  |     raise ImportError(
web_1  | ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
master_web_1 exited with code 1
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
    web:
        build: .
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        ports: 
            - "8000:8000"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED l
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app/
```

manage.py

#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'master.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

requirements.txt

```
Django==3.8.5
```

Comment: `docker-compose build` then `docker-compose up`

Comment: Thank for answer it can run now. but when open url localhost:8000. i found error on page  "A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator"

Comment: I found this issue now In my console docker  "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sql_server' "

Comment: since your `requirements.txt` contains only Django it's expected the DB library will be missing. But that's out of scope of this question already.

Answer (score -1):

Settings in config: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['']`

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

Comment: How does this solve the issue?

Answer (score -1):

This smells like a bad configuration issue. Try replacing the command with

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: Can you elaborate _what_ is configured wrong?

Comment: That error means that the python interpreter can't find the django folder. Which means that when you run the `python` command it goes look for it in a different folder than the one you think. That's why i suggested to run the command with `python3` instead because chances are that it will trigger the correct interpreter. Especially if you're on mac